# How to create an object of a custom class in Window PowerShell console?

Tags: powershell

I have created a simple class using Windows PowerShell ISE. The class definition is as follows.

```
class Person {
 [string] $FirstName
 [string] $LastName
    
    Person() {        
    }
    
    [string] Greeting() {
        return "Greetings, {0} {1}!" -f $this.FirstName, $this.LastName
    }
}
```

Now from within PowerShell console when I attempt to create an object from this class like this:

```
$x = [Person]::new()
```

It says

Unable to find type [Person].

Comment: Did you run the code to load the class in memory? Or did you dot source the file? Or did you `using module`?

Comment: This is as expected. Defining a new type in one process doesn't automatically define it in another.

Comment: Save the class as file "Person.ps1". Assuming you are in the same directory in the console, type: `. .\Person.ps1` to make the class available in the console. Note the space between the two dots! This is called [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing). Not the most scalable approach, but easy to use for simple stuff.

Comment: Ok. I dot-sourced my script and I'm able to successfully create the object like the following

 . F:\Per\PowerShell\PowerShell_Classes.ps1
$myobj = [Person]::new()

Bundle of thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your class definition is perfectly valid. The easiest way of starting to use your class is adding code in the same file below:

```
class Person {
 [string] $FirstName
 [string] $LastName
    
    Person() {        
    }
    
    [string] Greeting() {
        return "Greetings, {0} {1}!" -f $this.FirstName, $this.LastName
    }
}

# Using constructor
$x = [Person]::new()

# Setting up properties
$x.FirstName = "Alex"
$x.LastName = "K"

# Running a method
$x.Greeting()
```

> Greetings, Alex K!